# Recalling unicode from a python json dictionary is returning key error?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I have been trying to write an app that grabs the Reddit JSON and parses it into a nice list. However this dictionary is rather odd, so I have been parsing through it to try and get it to work.

Whenever I try I get a KeyError for u'data' (have tested, it is the first one)

To recall this I am trying `self.openit[u'data'][u'children'][i][u'data'][u'title']`
When I try that without the u the same thing happens. All Help is Appreciated!

Edit: I'm Dumb and forgot the json, here you go as a pastebin as this is very long

http://pastebin.com/0Yyb2BxJ

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON?

Comment: Try to provide, more information, it works with reddit [sample data](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Content%3A-reddits).

Comment: Don't know what else to provide, this is all I can figure, apologies if I asked a stupid question